# Android: напоминание посетить приложение после длительного простоя

Tags: android, android-notification

Довольно часто во всяких обучающих или игровых приложениях наблюдаю напоминалку (нотификацию) с призывами возобновить пользование. Стало интересно как подобное можно реализовать без сервера к примеру в 12 часов дня, не менее чем через сутки после последнего посещения, и через 4 дня, если активация так и не произошла.

Comment: Без сервера никак. Это делается правильно через push-notifications, которые сервер рассылает по каким-либо критериям приложению.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Такой сценарий я понимаю. Но надеюсь что кто-то сможет что-то да предложить дельного))

Comment: Запросто предложу дельное. Предлогаю решать так как это решается - с помощью сервера.

Comment: Без сервера можно так: записать в префы время последнего запуска. Через WorkManager раз в n времени проверять разницу меж записанным в префах и текущим временем. Если ОК - показывать уведомление. Но это, конечно, всё развалится если юзер вручную время на девайсе переведёт и да, менее надёжно и расширяемо, лучше с сервера делать

Comment: С серврера, само просто - связкой fairbase - cloud functions + notifications

Comment: AlarmManager ///

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Вникаю, пока что вроде бы то что нужно!) Спасибо)

Comment: AlarmManager. https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms